# What is the greater number?

Tags: arithmetic

I would like to prove that $100^{99}<99^{100}$.

My attempt:

$\dfrac{100^{99}}{99^{99}}<99$

$\left(\dfrac{100}{99}\right)^{99}<99$

$\left(\dfrac{2^2\cdot5^2}{3^2\cdot11}\right)^{99}<99$

$\dfrac{2^{198}\cdot5^{198}}{3^{198}\cdot11^{99}}<99$

But now I am stuck. Please can you help me?

Comment: @lulu Good year. Do leave my answer here or put it in the link?

Comment: @Sebastiano  Happy New Year to you as well.  I see no problem leaving the answer where it is, though my guess is that logs weren't meant to be involved in the solution here.  At least not numerical logs.  Usually this sort of problem is solved by looking at general properties of the function $F(x)=\frac {\ln x}x$.

Comment: I feel "greater" fits better than "greatest"

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are both larger than $2.718{\dots}$, it turns out that $x^y>y^x$ iff $y>x$. EDIT: Here's a graph. The region where $x^y>y^x$ is shaded. https://i.imgur.com/sI65P9Y.jpg

Comment: @lulu, why should this question be a duplicate of a question that was closed more than six years ago as off topic?

Comment: @PeterPhipps  It's an exact duplicate, with multiple highly upvoted answers.  In my view, this question should be closed either as a duplicate or because it, too, shows a lack of serious effort.  In my view, closing it as a duplicate is more informative (at least the OP gets their answer)...not sure what the official view on that is.

Answer (score 2):

$\log$ is a strictly increasing function on positive reals.

Let $x = 99^{100}$ and $y=100^{99}$; taking logarithm to the base $10$,

$$\log x = 100 \log 99 = 100\cdot 1.9956= 199.56$$

$$\log y= 99 \log 100= 99\cdot 2 = 198$$

Since $\log x > \log y$, $x$ is greater than $y$.